# Magento product import above 30 products magento hang

Tags: product

[image: hang image]

25 product import fine but when I create CSV above 30 product with images site hang I have already change php.ini with this option

```
memory_limit = 2048M 
max_file_uploads = 1000
upload_max_filesize = 512M
max_execution_time = 18000
mysql.connect_timeout = 400
post_max_size = 256M
max_input_nesting_level = 256

++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
htaccess code 
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
############################################
## uncomment these lines for CGI mode
## make sure to specify the correct cgi php binary file name
## it might be /cgi-bin/php-cgi
#    Action php5-cgi /cgi-bin/php5-cgi
#    AddHandler php5-cgi .php
############################################
## GoDaddy specific options
#   Options -MultiViews
## you might also need to add this line to php.ini
##     cgi.fix_pathinfo = 1
## if it still doesn't work, rename php.ini to php5.ini
############################################
## this line is specific for 1and1 hosting
    #AddType x-mapp-php5 .php
    #AddHandler x-mapp-php5 .php
############################################
## default index file
    DirectoryIndex index.php

############################################
## adjust memory limit
#    php_value memory_limit 64M
#    php_value memory_limit 256M
#    php_value max_execution_time 18000
############################################
## disable magic quotes for php request vars
    php_flag magic_quotes_gpc off
############################################
## disable automatic session start
## before autoload was initialized
    php_flag session.auto_start off
############################################
## enable resulting html compression
    #php_flag zlib.output_compression on
###########################################
# disable user agent verification to not break multiple image upload
    php_flag suhosin.session.cryptua off
###########################################
# turn off compatibility with PHP4 when dealing with objects
    php_flag zend.ze1_compatibility_mode Off


###########################################
# disable POST processing to not break multiple image upload
    SecFilterEngine Off
    SecFilterScanPOST Off


############################################
## enable apache served files compression
## http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#gzip
    # Insert filter on all content
    ###SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
    # Insert filter on selected content types only
    #AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/plain text/xml text/css text/javascript
    # Netscape 4.x has some problems...
    #BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html
    # Netscape 4.06-4.08 have some more problems
    #BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip
    # MSIE masquerades as Netscape, but it is fine
    #BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html
    # Don't compress images
    #SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI \.(?:gif|jpe?g|png)$ no-gzip dont-vary
    # Make sure proxies don't deliver the wrong content
    #Header append Vary User-Agent env=!dont-vary


############################################
## make HTTPS env vars available for CGI mode
    SSLOptions StdEnvVars


############################################
## enable rewrites
    Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine on
############################################
## you can put here your magento root folder
## path relative to web root
    #RewriteBase /magento/
############################################
## uncomment next line to enable light API calls processing
#    RewriteRule ^api/([a-z][0-9a-z_]+)/?$ api.php?type=$1 [QSA,L]
############################################
## rewrite API2 calls to api.php (by now it is REST only)
    RewriteRule ^api/rest api.php?type=rest [QSA,L]
############################################
## workaround for HTTP authorization
## in CGI environment
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
############################################
## TRACE and TRACK HTTP methods disabled to prevent XSS attacks
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^TRAC[EK]
    RewriteRule .* - [L,R=405]
############################################
## redirect for mobile user agents
    #RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/mobiledirectoryhere/.*$
    #RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "android|blackberry|ipad|iphone|ipod|iemobile|opera mobile|palmos|webos|googlebot-mobile" [NC]
    #RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /mobiledirectoryhere/ [L,R=302]
############################################
## always send 404 on missing files in these folders
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(media|skin|js)/
############################################
## never rewrite for existing files, directories and links
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
############################################
## rewrite everything else to index.php
    RewriteRule .* index.php [L]

############################################
## Prevent character encoding issues from server overrides
## If you still have problems, use the second line instead
    AddDefaultCharset Off
    #AddDefaultCharset UTF-8

############################################
## Add default Expires header
## http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#expires
    ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 year"

############################################
## By default allow all access
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
###########################################
## Deny access to release notes to prevent disclosure of the installed Magento version
    
        order allow,deny
        deny from all
    
############################################
## If running in cluster environment, uncomment this
## http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#etags
    #FileETag none
```

Comment: Are you sure this settings get used, due to the fact, that magento's .htaccess is changing the settings?

Comment: you can check my htaccess code

Comment: Is php using those settings if you output it though `phpinfo()` are those values set?

Comment: Enabling error reporting or developer mode and checking the logs would help here. Probably a memory limit issue

Answer (score 1):

issue has been resolved. Use these setting on php.ini

```
extension=pdo.so
extension=pdo_sqlite.so
extension=sqlite.so
extension=pdo_mysql.so
memory_limit = 8192M
max_file_uploads = 5000
upload_max_filesize = 512M
max_execution_time = 72000
mysql.connect_timeout = 2400
post_max_size = 512M
```

Answer (score 1):

After import process, magento will reindex all the indexer. 
due to this reason it is taking time or hanged up.

you can try following steps:

> Step 1: Set indexer mode to manually from ***System > Index Management > Mass Actions***
>
> Step 2: Import your products
>
> Step 3: Re-index Individually by clicking on "***Reindex Data***" action
>
> Step 4: Set indexer mode to "Update on Save"